# Short jump forwards and backwards

Tags: assembly, x86

In intel x86 assembly why does short jump with a value of 80 or higher move you to a lower address but the same instruction with a value of 0-79 move you to a higher address?

Can you not short jump higher for more than 0x79?

Comment: The offset given is given in two's complement.  So `0x80` represents an offset of -128.

Comment: It's a signed (twos-complement) 8-bit displacement.  So as normal, values `0x00-0x7f` are interpreted as positive, and `0x80-0xff` are negative.  If you need to jump by more than that, it's by definition not a short jump; you need a near jump instruction instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I would up vote you both if I could!

Comment: Intel's manual explains the encoding and range: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp